# Android native Code crashes in thumb mode but but not in arm mode

Tags: android-ndk, arm

I am trying to compile and run native code for android platform using android NDK.
In many places in the code I am trying to cast a short integer pointer to an integer pointer, hence its having memory alignment problems though it is working properly with X86. I am compiling the code in thumb mode, the code is carshing because of the unaligned access as i stated above. But if I compile the code in ARM mode, it is not crashing and working properly.

My doubt is why the code is not crashing in arm mode compilation, though it has memory alignment problems.

I am having very little knowledge about ARM and THUMB instruction sets. I know that ARM instrucions set is 32 bits wide and thumb is 16 bits wide. But how does it make a difference as concerned to the unaligned access?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the crash is caused by the instruction encoding length. ARM and Thumb mode should have the same ability to load *data* from aligned or unaligned addresses.

First, are you using real ARMv5 hardware that really doesn't allow unaligned 32bit loads? Because newer ARM chips, for example ARMv6 ([ARM11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM11)) chips that run Android compiled for ARMv5TE, can perform unaligned 32bit loads and won't crash. Of course, if your manifest states it's compiled for ARMv5TE then an Android device running on real ARMv5 hardware will happily install it and crash - it's your responsibility to make sure your app is really compatible with what it claims.

Qemu (including the emulator bundled in the Android SDK) does *not* correctly emulate crashing on unaligned 32bit loads when it emulates an [arm926ej-s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM9) (ARMv5TEJ) chip. You can't rely on the emulator to catch this. It's really only good for Java development, in this respect.

Can you see the crash in gdb? Can you show the register dump and see the load from an unaligned address? Are you sure the compiler doesn't change the meaning of your code (in an allowable way)?

For portability beyond x86, you are really not supposed to perform casts from `uint16_t*` to `uint32_t*`. The C language does not guarantee they would work. Technically, your code was always "wrong". Look at portable code in the wild: it uses preprocessor macros or static inline functions to abstract away concepts like "get_unaligned_le32" or whole functions that on x86 rely on unaligned access.

Answer (score 0):

Thumb instructions are 16bit long each while ARM ones are 32bit in size.

This means in ARM mode, it's guaranteed that the data section in the code is 4byte aligned, but not in Thumb mode.

You might try align directives. The align syntax varies depending on the compiler/assembler.

Some (hardware dependent) routines in some libraries assume the data to be 4byte aligned regardless of the data type.
If this condition is not met, it either crashes or the performance suffers heavily.

In addition, if you take the cache in consideration, it's wise to align performance critical data anyway. The cache-friendly alignment varies depending on SoC, but it's usually 32byte up to ARM11, 64byte on Coretex.

Comment: I also have a doubt that whether the crash is always define outcome of the misslligned memory access or some it may not crash? Since in my code there are  many pointers which have misalligned adress, but the code crashes with only few pointers not with all,  so please let me know your comments regarding this.

Comment: In thumb mode, there is 50% chance that the data is 4byte aligned. This explains the inconsistency.